# How do I share applications windows between OS X and Linux?

Tags: macos, screen-sharing, xdmx

I'm trying to set up Xdmx on my Macbook Pro and my Ubuntu 10.04 workstation so that I can share my MBP's keyboard and mouse as well as X applications running on the workstation across the laptop display, a laptop attached monitor, and the workstation's monitor.

1. Where do I find the latest Xdmx?  The Sourceforge site says that the code there is unmaintained and the project has been merged into Xserver.  I can't find an up to date source or binary distribution.
2. How do I install it?  Is there a package file? Do I have to build from source?
3. Are there other options for accomplishing what I've described above?

Comment: I think something similar is possible via VNC. You might want to look into that.

Comment: The problem with VNC is that it's more of a remote login tool so it ends up replicating the desktop rather than extending it.

Comment: [ScreenRecycler](http://www.screenrecycler.com/ScreenRecycler.html) is the software I meant. I'm just seeing now it's 30 USD, so it might not be for you. However, it could fit your requirements more generally. But I have not used it myself.

Comment: ScreenRecycler is the right idea. They don't seem to have a Linux version though.

Comment: You might want to generalize your question's title and text if a different solution ("ScreenRecycler for Linux") would also work for you.

Comment: To document my failure, via [alternative.to](http://alternativeto.net/software/screenrecycler/) I only found [Maxivista](http://www.maxivista.com/) (Windows only) and [QuickSynergy](http://code.google.com/p/quicksynergy/) (doesn't share the screen).

Answer (score 1):

> Are there other options for accomplishing what I've described above?

You can share your keyboard and mouse between OS X and Linux with [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/), but it doesn't let you share X applications, as far as I know.

[image]

Comment: Synergy might be part of my backup plan.  Unfortunately, in my environment, I might not be able to set up the laptop as the synergy server.

Comment: +1: even if it's not suited for the OP. :-/ Synergy is great when debugging network applications for example.